# Check if a discord message has a reference (is a reply)

Tags: python, reference, discord.py, command, bots

I try to make a command for my discord bot which should just work if it is used in a reply.
To check such a thing I thought I could use [`commands.check()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#checks), which basically adds a check to my command, so this is what I need.

However I am not sure how to use this function properly. I wrote a function that checks if a message has a reference (than it is a reply):

```
def check_if_message_is_reply(ctx):

    result = ctx.message.reference

    if result is None:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

So basically my check should return `False` (or a `False`-like value) if there is no reference. Adding this function to my check doesn't work as expected, the bot message gets never send. No matter if I use a reply or not:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$')

# define commands
@commands.command()
@commands.check(check_if_message_is_reply)
async def my_command(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Command worked, you used a reply')

client.add_command(my_command)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your check works fine, but you used the wrong decorator for your command. Since your function does not seem to be in a class, use `@client.command()` instead of `@commands.command()`.

Also using this decorator, you do not need `client.add_command`, it will be added automatically by discord.py

```py
@client.command()
@commands.check(check_if_message_is_reply)
async def my_command(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Command worked, you used a reply')
```